# How do I prevent GeForce from making changes to Skyrim

Tags: technical-issues, nvidia-geforce-experience

I have recently bought a game that requires GeForce Experience. When I 
installed GeForce, I realized that it made small changes to some of my games.
Most of the games it made changes too I enjoyed. However it made some changes to Skyrim that I didn't care for.

When I got on the game I noticed that the display was zoomed in, I also noticed that the brightness was different ( but it really isn't a problem), and the last thing was the blur of the screen when my player turned or moved too fast.

I realize that those things are probably improvements for the game, but after playing Skyrim for so long the way it was on my PC, the changes that GeForce made is just annoying.

I don't really want to uninstall GeForce cause the game I got was for both my brother and myself to have something to do together, and without GeForce it won't start. Any ideas or solutions would be great.

Comment: "I have recently bought a game that requires GeForce Experience" - what game is that? And why would a game require it? GFE isn't Steam and it's a userland application (no drivers or kernel components) so I'm perplexed.

Comment: @Dai Not all games are from steam... :)

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach He didn't say that the only place you can get games is Steam. He is saying GFE isn't DRM.

Comment: @gre_gor Oi!  I didn't realize that Steam had become a synonym for DRM...that's sad... :(

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach It hasn't, some people just love to hate. I own 150+ games on steam and exactly 3 use Steams DRM. The rest just use Steam as sales/deployment platform.

Comment: @Polygnome I'm not a Steam hater - I'm just stumped for why a game would require GFE because, to my knowledge, it doesn't provide any services or act as a platform for third-party applications.

Comment: @Dai I bought a new graphics card that came with a free copy of Rocket League. The only way to claim the license key was via Geforce Experience, which Nvidia are using (presumably) to make sure you are actually using the card you bought. I know this because I gave the card away as a present and could not claim the code (it said I wasn't using the card this code was valid for)

Comment: I personally feel that GFE is simply a resource user that provides very little benefit to a running machine.

Answer (score 71):

GeForce Experience is set to auto-optimize your games, which is why your games' settings change.

#### How to turn off auto-optimization

[image: Screenshot]

- Click on the cogwheel icon on the upper right.
- Select "Games" on the left.
- Uncheck "Automatically optimize newly added games" on the right.

---

#### How to manually optimize a game

[image: Screenshot]

- Click on "Home" on the upper left.
- Move your mouse over the game you want to optimize (in your case Skyrim).
- Click "Details".

[image: Screenshot]

- Finally, click "Optimize". You can also click on the icon to the right of "Optimize" to select a custom resolution or tweak how much the game will be optimized.

---

#### How to keep auto-optimization enabled, but revert a single game

- Select your game (Skyrim) as explained above.

[image: Screenshot]

- Click on "Revert".

Comment: Same answer as mine. lol. but the long path of it

Comment: @nolonar OMG, if this is the solution to why Overwatch has been crapping out recently on my computer I am going to drop a bounty....

Comment: @Malco. I doubt it is. GeForce Experience only changes the game's graphics settings to a set of values that are known to work well with your GPU. It shouldn't cause crashes or other issues.

Comment: @Nolonar ah, that is too bad. I don't know what is causing it but it only started in the last month or two. If I can't get it working right I will probably put up a question.

Comment: "Geforce Experience" indeed. Not only was it a royal pain to activate the "free" game that came with the card, but it also ruined two of the already installed games. Hopefully this will solve the problem.